# How to display only my costumes (created ) modules in Odoo (OpenERP)

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I would like to show only my custom module in Odoo interface, without displaying other Odoo Modules.

I have tried to assign my module to the user ( in user settings interface) and hidde other modules to him. But when the user login he see only the Web module, without the other modules.

For example:

I Odoo menu you can see the names of modules like : Sales, Calender ...etc

My goal is to hidde all module to users, and display only my module ( my costum module)

Any help please ... Thank you

Comment: Hello Mr. Zakaria, Your module inside create any security group?

Answer (score 0):

Inherit action for module list and add a domain

Try below code:

```
<record id="open_module_tree" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Apps</field>
        <field name="res_model">ir.module.module</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">kanban,tree,form</field>
        <field name="domain">[('name,'=','your_module_name')]</field>
        <field name="context">{'search_default_app':1}</field>
        <field name="search_view_id" ref="view_module_filter"/>
        <field name="help" type="html">
          <p><b>No module found!</b></p>
          <p>You should try other search criteria.</p>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Hope it will help you.